# Implementing Serializable in value object?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Firstly, some background on the `VO` here. The `VO`s are model object created in front-end tier to pass the value coming back from service tier.

Dummy code example below:

```
UserResponseTypeFromService user = userAccountService.getUser(...);
UserVO userVO = ServiceResponseHelper.getUserVOFromServiceResponse(user);
```

Then front-end code will only use `userVO` rather than `user` object.

My question is for `UserVO` class, do I have to implement `Serializable`? We should always consider thread safe in this situation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store the VO in session and/or want to transfer them across wire (DTO?) then you should implement Serializable.

VO's are just data holders and generally immutable. If you are following this principle then thread safety is a given (as they are immutable). Otherwise, you have to consider thread safety if you are storing them in session.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem statement seems a bit abstract/unclear but still I'll try to address your query to the best of my understanding.

Regarding serializable; make sure a class implements Serializable if the object of that class has to be persisted or sent across the wire. If your object doesn't fit the requirement, making it implement Serializable is not necessary (unless of course you plan to do something with the `serialVersionUID` field).

Regarding thread safe; can you clarify the context here?